# Products with category and sub categories

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am designing a website which is going to list 13,000 electronic products, first of all i want to be able to navigate through a side navigation which i have already created, would i store the categories of these electronic parts in the database? if so what is the best way to store categories? because i have some products with 3 tier categories for example

1. Semiconductors
2. Diode
3. Transorb.

As you can see i am a bit confused about how to do this in the database correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this. I'm suggesting this. First create two tables

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM(
ITEM_KEY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(255),
TYPE_CODE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ITEM_TYPECODE_CK CHECK(TYPE_CODE IN('ITEM','CATEGORY')),
CONSTRAINT ITEM_ITEMKEY PRIMARY KEY(ITEM_KEY)
);
```

Table Item is for Products and categories.

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMLINK(
ITEM_KEY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LINKED_ITEM_KEY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TYPE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ITEMLINK_ITEMKEY_LINKEDITEMKEY 
             PRIMARY KEY(ITEM_KEY, LINKED_ITEM_KEY,TYPE),
CONSTRAINT ITEMLINK_TYPE_CK CHECK(TYPE IN( 'CIL','CCL'))
);
```

Item Link table is for hierarchy. Item key is parent and linked item key is child. CIL means Category item Link and CCL means Category Category Link.

```
INSERT INTO ITEM (ITEM_KEY, "NAME", TYPE_CODE) VALUES ('IT01', 'Transorb', 'ITEM');
INSERT INTO ITEM (ITEM_KEY, "NAME", TYPE_CODE) VALUES ('CT01', 'Semiconductors', 'CATEGORY');
INSERT INTO ITEM (ITEM_KEY, "NAME", TYPE_CODE) VALUES ('CT02', 'Diode', 'CATEGORY');

INSERT INTO RWITEMLINK (ITEM_KEY, LINKED_ITEM_KEY, "TYPE") VALUES ('CT01', 'CT02', 'CCL');
INSERT INTO RWITEMLINK (ITEM_KEY, LINKED_ITEM_KEY, "TYPE") VALUES ('CT02', 'IT01', 'CIL');
```

Now you can iterate with ItemLink table to populate list.